# Firefox simple form element with inner html bug

Tags: html, firefox, innerhtml

If the below code was opened in firefox 20.0.1 and type some value in the text box. once after typing the value hit the browser refresh button. the typed value getting shifted from one input elelment to another.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function searchPageLoader(){
            document.getElementById('searchareaa').innerHTML='<label ></label>';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="searchPageLoader()">
    <div id="searchareaa"></div>
    <input type="text" id="pageCount" value="5"/>
    <input type="text" id="startlimit" value="11"/>
    <input type="text" id="endlimit" value="5"/>
</body>
</html>
```

It is happening only in firefox and and only if we do the innerhtml . What is the work around for this, as it is spoiling most of the application workflow.

Comment: And the question is? If there's no question, file a bug report on Mozilla's bug tracker, instead of asking a question here.

Answer (score 0):

If you surround the form controls (including the div with the new label) with `<form></form>` tags, this strange behavior disappears. See https://support.mozilla.org/questions/959372